# Build from command line isn't picking up latest version of C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

In my Jenkins build I use the following to setup and build my project:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 JetCutStudies.sln
```

This mostly works. Until recently everything was building. But I've not started including some C# 7/7.1 language features. In the VS2017 IDE this builds fine, but I get errors when building from the above command line (tested on the same machine).

In short, it looks like vsvars32.bat isn't picking up the correct version of things.

How can I get the command line to build with the proper version of the C# compiler?

Comment: Learn what is `vswhere` and use it to locate CS2017 path.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of vswhere! A choco install of vswhere, and usage as described on vswhere's website did the trick (https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere). Do you want to write an answer or shall I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft changed Visual Studio 2017 installation, so that

- Different editions can install side by side
- Preview builds can install side by side

As a result of such fundamental changes, you cannot use hard code paths to locate any Visual Studio components (MSBuild, any script and so on).

The new utility [vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere) can help locate the root installation folder, and then other paths can be calculated from it.